# Position JDialog nearby its parent

Tags: java, swing, layout, position, jdialog

I'd like to position a JDialog nearby it's parent as showed in this picture:

[image]

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
JDialog.setLocation(parent.getX() + parent.getWidth(), parent.getY() + parent.getHeight() - (parent.getHeight() / 2 + JDialog.getHeight() / 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

An even easier way to do it to just reference the parent once:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component)